# cannot display Moo Tools Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, mootools

I've got some questions about Moo Tools Date Picker.

I am using the following versions:

```
  mootools-core-1.5.0.js
  mootools-more-1.5.0.js
  jquery-1.11.1.js
  jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js
  jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
  datepicker-2.2.0-0
```

I am trying to make a date picker pop up when I press a button.

The button is defined as follows:

```
    <button id="myLink" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Press This</button>
```

I've got the following style included:

```
    <link href="Source/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I think I ran into some conflict with Moo Tools and jQuery's use of $ so I have:

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
```

This is how I make Date Picker display when the button is pressed:

```
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

    myPicker = new Picker.Date($$('button.myLink'), {
        startDay: '0',
        positionOffset: {x: 50, y: 50},
        onSelect: function(date){
                doSomething(date)
        }
    });

    $('myLink').addEvent('click', function(e){
        console.log("opening picker e="+e);
        e.stop();
        myPicker.open();
    });
     });
```

I believe $('myLink').addEvent(.... is a Moo Tools method.  Is that correct?

The problems are:

the calendar pop up appears at 0,0 as opposed to 50,50

the calendar pop up is a blank, white window

I'm at a loss as to how to correct this.  If you were faced with this, how would you go about fixing these problems?

Comment: Did you apply the changes made when you used `noConflict()` to your jQuery code? If yes, then there should be no issue of conflicts.

Comment: Juan - do you mean replacing $ with jQuery?  Yes, i did that.

Comment: Check your external js as well. If you think conflict is really the issue, try to make the date picker work in a plain new page first before including other js script like jQuery just to identify what really the cause of it.

Comment: What do you mean by external js?  I don't want to guess and get it wrong and delay delivery of this any longer.

Comment: `$('myLink').addEvent('click', function(e){` is a MooTools code, you are right. Can you precise which datepicker you use? Is it Arian's? can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: yes, i am using arian's.  i tried making a jsFiddle, how do i include date picker?  do i have to host it myself?